# how to remove the publishing options in drupal

Tags: drupal

I am using work flow module.
I dont want the publishing options to be displayed while we are trying to create a page .
How is it possible..

Comment: While I am using work flow I am giving the publishing options only to the publisher and not to the editor. My work flow is working fine but the publishing options is being displayed which should not happen how can i overcome with this...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found for this exact problem is to disable *administer nodes* permission for all users who's involved in the publication workflow. This will hide the publishing options for all users. What you'll aim for is to let the system handle the publication, and not the users.

If you combine the Workflow module with modules Revisioning, Actions and Trigger you can trigger an action that publishes your page when your content reaches the final workflow status. The process is more or less documented in the documentation for http://drupal.org/project/revisioning.

I have setup this with statuses *Draft*, *For review*, *Needs work* and *Approved* for our Intranet. When a publisher set content into *Approved* status, the Trigger/Action modules handles the publication of the content.

Answer (score 1):

The publishing options fieldset is displayed for users who have the **administer nodes** permission.  Keep in mind that while you may see it if you are a member of a role that has been granted the permission (or are logged in as user #1), other users who have other roles will not have access to it.  Make sure to view the form as a user with the same permissions as the users who will be using the form, not just with an administrative account.

If you need better control over the fieldset's display, then you will have to use `hook_form_alter` as sprugman mentioned.

Comment: I want to give the administer nodes permission but i dont want to display the publishing options field.......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're comfortable with PHP, the best way is probably with [the FAPI](http://drupal.org/node/751826). You'll need to [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) the node creation form for the insert state. It might be best to change the type of the fields to hidden inputs rather than removing them, but I don't know enough about how workflow works to be sure.

You can probably also do it with css.

Answer (score 0):

... or use the module http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options ? Desccription:

> The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each field within the Authoring information and Publishing options field sets on the node form. It also allow selected field sets to be set as collapsed and / or collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 you can use [Jammer](https://drupal.org/project/jammer) module.